# Mac Terminal process ends and outputs [Process completed] when launched

Tags: macos, terminal

When I launch the Terminal app on Mac, the process will end and output the following:

```
Last login: Wed Aug  6 15:53:58 on ttys003

[Process completed]
```

This started happening when terminal froze and I restarted it. From then on, this is the message that is displayed.

I can change the Shell to `bin/sh` in Terminal's preferences, but this prevents me from using my `.bash_profile` script.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions on how to fix this?

Thanks!

PS Here's my .bash_profile. I tried commenting it out and running Terminal and it still didn't work, but here is per request.

```
export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"

##
# Your previous /Users/mjmitchener/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/mjmitchener/.bash_profile.macports-saved_2013-05-06_at_09:58:31
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2013-05-06_at_09:58:31: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.

### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"

### Composer Vendor Paths
export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"

### Bin Paths
export PATH="bin:$PATH"

### Vendor Paths
export PATH="vendor/bin:$PATH"

### Aliases
#
# Directories
alias partways='cd ~/Sites/projects/PartWays/'
alias trks='cd ~/Sites/projects/ThingsRichKidsSay/'
alias forrest='cd ~/Sites/projects/rest-client/workbench/omniphx/forrest/'
alias blog='cd ~/Sites/projects/blog'
alias tinynews='cd ~/Sites/projects/tinynews'

# Laravel Commands
alias art='php artisan'
alias l4project=''

# Generator Stuff
alias g:m="php artisan generate:model"
alias g:c="php artisan generate:controller"
alias g:v="php artisan generate:view"
alias g:s="php artisan generate:seed"
alias g:mig="php artisan generate:migration"
alias g:r="php artisan generate:resource"


# Node scripts
alias node_serve='node ./scripts/web-server.js'

#Git aliases
alias ggraph='git log --oneline --all --graph --decorate'
alias ga='git add'
alias gaa='git add .'
alias gau='git add -u'
alias gco='git checkout'
alias gst='git status'
alias gc='git commit'
alias gcm='git commit -m'
alias gca='git commit -a'
alias gcam='git commit -am'
alias gls='git ls-tree HEAD'

#PHPUnit

#Vagrant
alias vm='ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222'

#Sqlite3
alias db='sqlite3 app/database/production.sqlite'
```

Comment: Is there anything in your `.bash_profile` script that could be causing this?

Comment: There must be; OP: please add the contents of `.bash_profile` to your question.

Comment: Tried commenting out the `.bash_profile` completely and it still wasn't working. I'll post it anyways though.

Comment: Check Terminal's preferences, on the Startup tab, "Shells open with:". Make sure it's sensible.

Comment: @KenThomases, it's set to default when the issue is happening. I've been setting it to `bin/sh` as a work around. However, after running the `login` command my `.bash_profile` script no longer works. So hopefully I can fix the default setting or find a work around.

Comment: Ended up figuring out that `/bin/bash` was corrupted.

Used Homebrew to install it again and replaced the old `bash` file with the one that Homebrew installed. Works perfectly now... very weird.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread but still relevant. It seems the only way to fix this without having to do workarounds that cause other issues, is to reinstall the OS. Its been a common issue since 2000.

Comment: Hi @hoodun, I just reinstalled `/bin/bash` with Homebrew and it worked again. Must have been corrupted somehow.

Answer (score 0):

By trying above steps you will solve this problem.

1. Delete node module of the project.
2. npm install
3. cd ios(if ios is configured)
4. now run your app.